# Powershell get-date in 1st,2nd,2rd,4th Formats

Tags: powershell

I am trying to format a `date` in PowerShell as `DayOfWeek Month Day(st|nd|rd|th) year` format.

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(+1).ToString('D')
```

The output is "Tuesday, July 05, 2016"
but need it in this format: **Tuesday July 5th 2016**

```
if date(Get-Date) % 100 IN (11, 12, 13) THEN 'th'
    if (Get-Date) % 10 = 1 THEN 'st'
    if (Get-Date) % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd'
    if (Get-Date) % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution could look like this

```
function Get-DateOrdinalSuffix([datetime]$Date) {
    switch -regex ($Date.Day.ToString()) {
        '1(1|2|3)$' { 'th'; break }
        '.?1$'      { 'st'; break }
        '.?2$'      { 'nd'; break }
        '.?3$'      { 'rd'; break }
        default     { 'th'; break }
    }
}

$d = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
$suffix = Get-DateOrdinalSuffix $d
$dateFormatted = "{0} {1:MMMM} {2}{3} {4}" -f $d.DayOfWeek, $d, $d.Day, $suffix, $d.Year
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without using `regex` to get the day suffix:

```
function Get-DaySuffix
{
    Param(
        [System.DateTime]$date
    )

    switch ($date.Day)
    {
        {$_ -in 1,21,31} { 'st'}
        {$_ -in 2,22} { 'nd'}
        {$_ -in 3,23} { 'rd'}
        Default {'th'}
    }
}

$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
$output = $date.ToString('dddd MMMM d yyyy', [CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-US'))
$output -replace '( \d{4})$', ('{0}$1'-f (Get-DaySuffix $date))
```

**Output:**

```
Tuesday July 5th 2016
```